# Themes.xml not working on appcompat 23

Tags: android, xml, themes

I was developing an app that used max api 21 and appcompat-v7:21.0.0 library. After migrating to api 23 and appcompat to this same version, themes.xml don`t have effect on api 21 and above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AAAActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AAAActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AAAPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/AAAPopupMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AAAPopupMenuButtonOverflow</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AAAActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/AAAPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AAAActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/action_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AAAPopupMenu"
        parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/action_bar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/action_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AAAPopupMenuTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AAAPopupMenuButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_overflow</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Can someone help me with this problem? 
Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in AppCompat 23 only known solution was change to new Toolbar with extending AppCompatActivity and then set it with setSupportActionBar(toolbar)